# Error while installing SciPy.stats

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, statsmodels

I'm trying to import scipy.stats on Python 3.5. windows 10.

I am keep getting ImportError: cannot import name 'ellipkm1'.

The Scipy is up to date.
The full Error code-

```
from scipy import stats
```

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#76>", line 1, in <module>
    from scipy import stats
  File "C:\Users\Oriel Perkal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\__init__.py", line 321, in <module>
    from .stats import *
  File "C:\Users\Oriel Perkal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\stats.py", line 180, in <module>
    import scipy.special as special
  File "C:\Users\Oriel Perkal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\scipy\special\__init__.py", line 603, in <module>
    from .basic import *
  File "C:\Users\Oriel Perkal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\scipy\special\basic.py", line 14, in <module>
    from ._ufuncs import (ellipkm1, mathieu_a, mathieu_b, iv, jv, gamma, psi, zeta,
ImportError: cannot import name 'ellipkm1'
```

Comment: What did you use to install SciPy?

Comment: You can save a lot of headaches in Windows by using the Anaconda's python distribution.

Comment: I installed scipy-0.16.1-cp35-none-win32.whl using pip

Comment: @jfish003 true but numpy is needed for scipy. Did you install/include numpy?

Comment: Yes numpy is working correctly

Comment: Is scipy working properly? Can you use other scipy functions like linalg?

Comment: when I import linalg from scipy i'm not receiving any errors.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem too

Try installing Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable [package](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145).
Just remember install the version x64 or x86 basing on your python version not your OSVersion.